# Firewall rules on the registry

Tags: registry, windows-firewall

I need to understand the nomenclature of firewall rules in the registry, that some have parameters that I do not know, such as these

```
v2.27 | Action = Allow | Active = TRUE | Dir = Outside | Profile = Public | IFType = Wireless | Name = @ {Microsoft.PPIProjection_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy? ms-resource: //Microsoft.PPIProjection/resources/ProductName} | Desc = @ {Microsoft.PPIProjection_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy? Ms-resource: //Microsoft.PPIProjection/resources/ProductName} | LUOwn = S-1-5-21-3970781290-3845840628-3602084687-1001 | AppPkgId = S- 1-15-2-1162584699-752881360-2552798240-2633183829-2219405937-1046343680-2483954874 | EmbedCtxt = @ {Microsoft.PPIProjection_10.0.16299.15_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy? Ms-resource: //Microsoft.PPIProjection/resources/ProductName} | Platform = 2: 6: 2 | Platform2 = GTEQ | TTK2_22 = WFDDevices |


v2.27 | Action = Allow | Active = TRUE | Dir = In | Protocol = 6 | LPort2_10 = IPTLSIn | LPort2_10 = IPHTTPSIn | App = System | Name = @ FirewallAPI.dll, -25426 | Desc = @ FirewallAPI.dll, - 25428 | EmbedCtxt = @ FirewallAPI.dll, -25000 |
```

besides this in the registry there are 3 keys, you are looking for rules, and I still do not understand what each one does.

Firewall
RestrictedServices \ Configurable \ System
RestrictedServices \ Static \ System

Comment: And why exactly?

Comment: The 
nomenclature used

Comment: Does anyone know what "v" (the first item) means?

Comment: @Corio, V for Vendetta (haha). Actually, VERSION=[MAJOR_VER.MINOR_VER], where MAJOR_VER is high order 8 bits of the wSchemaVersion field of the FW_RULE structure as defined in [MS-FASP] section 2.2.36 and the same for MINOR_VER.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to MSDN documentation with the description of all possible fields:

[Firewall Rule and the Firewall Rule Grammar Rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff719844.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)